# unable to create a plot form file data in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to draw a 2d plot in python using x and y data sets in two files named `x` and `y`, but it fails with the following error:

```
plt.plot(func(x,y))
errror: name 'x' is not defind
```

and here's my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def func(x,y):
f = open("./x.txt","r")
 x = f.read().splitlines()
 f = open("./y.txt","r")
 y = f.read().splitlines()
 plt.plot(func(x,y))
 plt.xlabel('توضیح عمودی')
 plt.ylabel('توضیح افقی')
 plt.show()
```

What am I doing wrong???

Answer (score 0):

You are very close. Your error just mean that you haven't initialize `x` when you call it. You should take care of indentation and the order of the line.

Here is a working example:

```
# Import module
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read files
f = open("./x.txt", "r")
x = f.read().splitlines()
f = open("./y.txt", "r")
y = f.read().splitlines()

# Define your plot function
def plotXY(x,y):
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.xlabel('توضیح عمودی')
    plt.ylabel('توضیح افقی')
    plt.show()

# Call the plot function
plotXY(x,y)
```

Hope that help !